# RouteHandler for Static Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, custom-routes

We want to route all static content (js, css, images - png, gif, jpeg, jpg) of our application to a RouteHandler. Where we'll do [Best Practices for Speeding up Web Sites](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html). Like adding ETags, Cache Control, Expires, etc for all our static content.

How can we do that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure most of that can be done with IIS ...

Comment: @Martin I would agree but there are scenarios in which you would need a handler like images need to have 'ETag' or 'If-Modified-Since' but not user profile images as they can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You should really do it in IIS.

But if you want to have total control over it (can't find a good reason though!), you can add a catch all route as your last route. Something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Static",
    "{*path}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Static"});
```

Then add an action to your control to handle it:

```
public ActionResult Static(string path)
{
    //path is everything you get after the /
    //Use Server.MapPath to load it
    //Add headers to response, etc
    return File();
}
```

But this is really bad in my opinion. The most obvious thing is taking the path from the URL and map it to server. What happens if the path is `/../../Windows/...`? Probably nothing, but I don't like it.